# Training and test set with loops in R

Tags: r

I have prepared my data and I called it `wdbc_n`. The dimension of the data is (569)(32). I separated this data using Leave one out cross validation. The following is my code for data partition

```
LOOOCV_training=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc_n)){
LOOOCV_training[[i]]=wdbc_n[-i,]}

LOOOCV_testing=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc_n)){
LOOOCV_testing[[i]]=wdbc_n[i,]}
```

Now, my question is how to select my training or test set to build a model for example?

I am confused because they are in loops form.

What I want is how to deal with them because I will have many training and test sets (569). For example, if I have one train set and I want to write some codes I will do like this `for (i in 1:nrow(wdbc_train))...` but now It is many, It is time-consuming to write one by one.

Now suppose I want to use LOOCV solution above with the following part of my previous codes. How could this happen?

```
Dist=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_train),ncol=nrow(wdbc_test)) 

Dist2=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_test),ncol=3) 

 for (i in 1:nrow(wdbc_train)){ 
    for (j in 1:nrow(wdbc_test)){

Dist[i,j]=lpnorm(as.matrix(wdbc_train[i,]- wdbc_test[j,]),0.1)}}
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you just want to create a `data.frame` from the `LOOOCV_testing` and `LOOOCV_training`? If so, use `do.call(rbind, LOOCV_testing)` and the same with training.

Comment: Ah, just use `lapply` to loop over the list of datasets. Lets say you want to test a linear model `var1 ~ var2`, use `model1 <- lapply(LOOOCV_training, function(x) lm(var1 ~ var2, data = x))`

Comment: @LAP, thanks, still a little bit confused. Now  suppose I want to use your solution with this part of my previous codes. How this could happen? `Dist=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_train),ncol=nrow(wdbc_test)) 
Dist2=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_test),ncol=3)
indL=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_test),ncol=3)
for (i in 1:nrow(wdbc_train)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(wdbc_test)){
    Dist[i,j]=lpnorm(as.matrix(wdbc_train[i,]-wdbc_test[j,]),0.1)}}`